# How can I look up values which are indirectly linked to my dataframe?

Tags: r, lookup

I'd like some ideas/solutions for the following example. I have two tables, `deals.df` and `turnover.df`. Please see a toy example below which reflects what they look like:

```
deals.df <- data.frame(DealID = c(100101, 100102, 100103, 100104),
                       CompanyName= c('ABC', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'HIJ'),
                       DealYear = c(2013,2014,2015,2013),
                       DealYearL1= deals.df$DealYear-1,
                       DealYearP1= deals.df$DealYear+1,
                       DealYearL1Turnover= c('?', '?', '?', '?'),
                       DealYearTurnover= c('?', '?', '?', '?'),
                       DealYearP1Turnover= c('?', '?', '?', '?'))

turnover.df <- data.frame(CompanyName=c('ABC', 'DEF', 'HIJ'),
                          Turnover2011= c(100, 150, 180),
                          Turnover2012=c(110, 160, 200),
                          Turnover2013= c(125, 175, 210),
                          Turnover2014= c(135,180,230),
                          Turnover2015= c(145, 200, 235),
                          Turnover2016= c(160, 220, 250))
```

Note `DealYearL1` means "Deal year less 1" and `DealYearP1` means "Deal year plus one". What I want to do is populate the variables with "?". The logic is something like this:

For each `DealID` in `deals.df`, find the turnover associated with that `CompanyName` in `turnover.df` in the year before the deal, the year of the deal, and the year after the deal (ie the variables with '?' values). So for example the top row would look like this:

```
#Ideal output in deals.df

DealID   CompanyName   DealYear   DealYearL1   DealYearP1   DealYearL1Turnover   DealYearTurnover     DealYearP1Turnover
100101   ABC          2013         2012         2014           110                     125                135
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility using `tidyverse` (assuming variables in `turnover.df` are in order of year - if not ordered, would `arrange` before `mutate`):

```
library(tidyverse)

long.df <- turnover.df %>%
  rename_at(vars(starts_with("Turnover")), ~ str_replace(., "^(Turnover)", "\\1_")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Turnover"), 
               names_to = c(".value", "DealYear"), 
               names_sep = "_",
               names_ptypes = list(DealYear = numeric())) %>%
  group_by (CompanyName) %>%
  mutate(DealYearL1Turnover = lag(Turnover),
         DealYearP1Turnover = lead(Turnover)) %>%
  rename(DealYearTurnover = Turnover)

deals.df %>%
  left_join(long.df, by = c("CompanyName", "DealYear"))
```

**Output**

```
  DealID CompanyName DealYear DealYearL1 DealYearP1 DealYearTurnover DealYearL1Turnover DealYearP1Turnover
1 100101         ABC     2013       2012       2014              125                110                135
2 100102         ABC     2014       2013       2015              135                125                145
3 100103         DEF     2015       2014       2016              200                180                220
4 100104         HIJ     2013       2012       2014              210                200                230
```

**Data**

```
deals.df <- data.frame(DealID = c(100101, 100102, 100103, 100104),
                       CompanyName= c('ABC', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'HIJ'),
                       DealYear = c(2013,2014,2015,2013))

deals.df$DealYearL1= deals.df$DealYear-1
deals.df$DealYearP1= deals.df$DealYear+1

turnover.df <- data.frame(CompanyName=c('ABC', 'DEF', 'HIJ'),
                          Turnover2011= c(100, 150, 180),
                          Turnover2012= c(110, 160, 200),
                          Turnover2013= c(125, 175, 210),
                          Turnover2014= c(135, 180, 230),
                          Turnover2015= c(145, 200, 235),
                          Turnover2016= c(160, 220, 250))
```